# Register Page redirects to Login Page even with AllowAnonymous Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, forms-authentication

I have used forms authentication to let users login to my website. However, the users cannot access the Register page without logging in, even though the Register action has the [AllowAnonymous] Attribute added.

My AccountController Action is:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View("Register");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register(RegistrationModel registrationModel)
    {
        if (new UserAccounts().DoesUserExist(registrationModel.UserName, registrationModel.Email))
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "User with same email or Username Already Exists");
        else
        {
            new UserAccounts().CreateUser(registrationModel);
            TempData["Success"] = "User has been created!";
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The News controller action for showing content only to authenticated users is:

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult News()
    {
        HomeNewsModel HomeNewsModel = null;

        try
        {
            ViewBag.IsNewsPage = true;
            NewsArticles NewsItems = new NewsArticles();
            ViewBag.Title = "Home";
            HomeNewsModel = new HomeNewsModel();
            HomeNewsModel.AllNews = NewsItems.GetAllNews();
            HomeNewsModel.NewsCategory = new NewsArticles().GetCategories();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        return View(HomeNewsModel);
    }
```

And here is my Web.Config File:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <configuration>
       <appSettings>
         <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
         <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
         <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
         <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
       </appSettings>
       <connectionStrings>
         <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="server = localhost; uid = root; password= admin; persistsecurityinfo=True;database=sqlexpressdb;" />

       </connectionStrings>

       <system.web>
         <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error/" mode="Off" />
         <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
         <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
       <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
       </authentication>
       </system.web>
       <location path="Account/Register">
         <system.web>
             <authorization>
             <allow users="?"/>
             </authorization>
         </system.web>
     </location>
       <runtime>

         <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
           <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
           </dependentAssembly>
           <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
           </dependentAssembly>
           <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
           </dependentAssembly>
         </assemblyBinding>
       </runtime>
       <system.codedom>
         <compilers>
           <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
             type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
           <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
             type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
         </compilers>
       </system.codedom>
     </configuration>
```

Things I've tried:

1. Putting the [AllowAnonymous] attribute at the top of the controller
2. Using location path="Register" / path="~/Register" /path="~/Account/Register...   in web.config

Removing [Authorize] attribute from the News controller opens the Register page when I click on it.
Removing  with [Authorize] attribute enabled in the News Controller Action opens the Register page when I type it in the URL.

However, it keeps redirecting to Login page with both the combinations enabled.

Comment: are you rendering any action in the "_Layout" page which is accessible to authorized users only? Verify if you have Html.Action or Html.RenderAction in _Layout page and if those actions has Authorize attribute. This most likely to be the case.

Comment: This was exactly the problem.
I had a Html.Action instead of Html.ActionLink embedded in an image.

Rookie mistake because I'm still a rookie!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glad it helped :)

Just posting here as an answer so people visiting the question may also get help for similar issue.

*In such cases, the first thing we need to verify that the layout page of the CSHTML page, as well as any partial view in the complete hierarchy must not have @Html.Action or @Html.RenderAction rendering an action having Authorize attribute.*

Comment: It worked, I was calling an @Html.Action with Authorize into html comments. Thanks